# Topological Structure of Finite Set

Tags: general-topology

I encounter with a problem in *Topological Manifold* written by *Lee*:

> How many different topological structure of $\{1,2,3\}$?

It is easy to make a list of the question, and the answer is $9$.

However I am interested in the more general case: $\{1,2,\cdots,n\}$. My question is obviously that how many structure on it classified by homeomorphism. Is there any general formula?

Thanks in any help.

Comment: This is an interesting problem, but there is not really a nice formula. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_topological_space#Number_of_topologies_on_a_finite_set), and [here](http://oeis.org/A001930).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an open problem with a lot of devolopment. You should take a look here

http://journals.cambridge.org/download.php?file=%2FJAZ%2FJAZ8_02%2FS1446788700005231a.pdf&code=ad4ac623d5c04ebc83c2e95bce65491e

http://www.emis.de/journals/JIS/VOL9/Benoumhani/benoumhani11.pdf